# Unmarshalling SOS GetCapabilities via JSONIX yields only abstract offering data

Tags: jsonix

I am trying to use jsonix to unmarshall a GetCapabilities response from SOS_2_0. Below is the code I wrote to unmarshall the xml string. It seems to work fine however not all of the elements have been mapped correctly.

```
function jsonixParseSensors(xmlStr) {
      var module = SOS_2_0_Module_Factory();
      var context = new Jsonix.Context([XLink_1_0, GML_3_2_1, OWS_1_1_0, SWE_2_0, SWES_2_0, WSN_T_1, WS_Addr_1_0_Core, OM_2_0, ISO19139_GMD_20070417, ISO19139_GCO_20070417, ISO19139_GSS_20070417, ISO19139_GTS_20070417, ISO19139_GSR_20070417, Filter_2_0, SOS_2_0]);
      var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
      var data = unmarshaller.unmarshalString(xmlStr);
      return data;
}
```

In the screenshot below it is apparent all of the 'offerings' in 'contents' are defaulted to the abstract type (SWES_2_0.AbstractContentsType.Offering) and have no information about the sensor/observation offering in them. It's odd because other elements such as 'filtercapabilities' contain all the info and attributes as well. I have tried this both with and without passing namespacing arguments to unmarshallString and it does not seem to make a difference. Is there something I am fundamentally misunderstanding?

[image].

[image]

[SOS GetCapabilities xml from Botts-Geo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8LdnPVJpHz7YnVSVlBCSFczNGM/view?usp=sharing)

[SOS GetCapabilities xml from Sensiasoft](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8LdnPVJpHz7Ri16RXdKR2QwQms/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please show your XML.

Comment: Edit includes a screenshot of the xml now

Comment: I can't immediately spot a problem. Could you prepare a fiddle? Like this one: https://jsfiddle.net/lexi/6skd7x8u/

Comment: Looks like a bug, actually. You should be getting your offerings as `abstractOffering` properties. Please send me your XML.

Comment: The full xml files are uploaded and available as links now. Let me know if you have any issues accessing.

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/issues/174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `SWES_2_0` mapping. The `abstractOffering` property of the `SWES_2_0.AbstractContentsType.Offering` type was [generated](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/9a81a771851b90f323356a02374c2663b248b8b4/scripts/lib/SWES_2_0.js#L498-L507) as "element" property:

```
  {
    ln: 'AbstractContentsType.Offering',
    tn: null,
    ps: [{
        n: 'abstractOffering',
        rq: true,
        en: 'AbstractOffering',
        ti: '.AbstractOfferingType'
      }]
  }
```

This should have been an "element reference" property to allow the `swes:AbstractOffering` element to be replaced by other elements via substitution groups.

This should be fixed now in [ogc-schemas](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) trunk, see the [test](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/0b44fd1ac49c506e0e0d4f76b7c0ff78c9a71a58/scripts/tests/SOS/2.0/SOS_2_0.js#L27).

Comment: It works now, thanks so much for the timely response and even more for your contributions with jsonix and the ogc-schemas. Very impressive work!

Comment: @user2714417 Thank you.